# tengo duda de una sentencia de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

SELECT  a.IDCliente,a.CveAduana,a.CvePedimento,b.NombreCliente,IdRegimen,TipoEmbalaje, CveRegimen, Buque, Booking, Proveedor, isnull(CantidadBultos,0), d.Id, a.TipoPedimento, c.ReferenciaCliente
FROM REP_Archivos a
INNER JOIN ctCLIENTES b on b.IDCliente=a.IDCliente
LEFT JOIN REP_ArchivosComplemento c on c.IdArchivo=a.IDArchivo
LEFT JOIN REP_CorreosNotificacion d on d.CveAduana=a.CveAduana and d.IdCliente=a.IDCliente and d.Correo=c.Correos
WHERE a.ArchivoInstruccion =@ArchivoInstruccion

Comment: No edites la pregunta para cambiar todo el contenido. Crea una nueva pregunta con detalles

Answer (score 3):

Las opciones 1, 2, 3 y 4 son para obtener las colindancias del predio. No están filtrando los datos de la consulta en sí. Una forma más eficiente y clara de escribir esta consulta sería usando un agregado condicional y usar alias para las tablas.

```
SELECT ALS.STrasladoDominioFecha
    ,AP.PredioCveCatastral
    ,XP.NombreCompletoPersona
    ,AP.PredioCalle
    ,(SELECT CONCAT(
                    MAX( CASE WHEN PC.PredioColindanciasId = 1 THEN PC.PredioColindanciasDescripcion + ' ' ELSE '' END),
                    MAX( CASE WHEN PC.PredioColindanciasId = 2 THEN PC.PredioColindanciasDescripcion + ' ' ELSE '' END),
                    MAX( CASE WHEN PC.PredioColindanciasId = 3 THEN PC.PredioColindanciasDescripcion + ' ' ELSE '' END),
                    MAX( CASE WHEN PC.PredioColindanciasId = 4 THEN PC.PredioColindanciasDescripcion ELSE '' END))
        FROM AL28PredioColindancias PC
        WHERE PC.PredioId = ALS.PredioId) AS Colindancias
    ,AP.PredioTotalTerreno
    ,AP.PredioTotalConstruccion
    ,AP.PredioTerrenoImporte
    ,AP.PredioConstruccionImporte
    ,ALS.STrasladoDominioAvaluoCatastral
    ,ALS.STrasladoDominioAvaluoBancario
    ,ALS.STrasladoDominioId
    ,ALS.STrasladoDominioPrecioPactado
    ,ALS.STrasladoDominioQrooReciboSerie
    ,ALS.STrasladoDominioQrooRecibofOLIO
    ,ALNO.NotarioNombre AS Expr1
    ,ALNA.NotariaDireccion
    ,ALNA.NotariaTelefono
FROM       AlPredio AP
INNER JOIN XiPersonas XP          ON AP.CvePersona                   = XP.CvePersona
INNER JOIN ALSTRASLADODOMINIO ALS ON AP.CveFteMT                     = ALS.CveFteMT
                                 AND AP.PredioId                     = ALS.PredioId
                                 AND XP.CveFteMT                     = ALS.CveFteMT
INNER JOIN ALNOTARIA ALNA         ON ALS.CveFteMT                    = ALNA.CveFteMT
INNER JOIN ALNOTARIO ALNO         ON ALNA.NotariaPaisId              = ALNO.NotariaPaisId
                                 AND ALNA.NotariaEntidadFederativaId = ALNO.NotariaEntidadFederativaId
                                 AND ALNA.NotariaMunicipioId         = ALNO.NotariaMunicipioId
                                 AND ALNA.NotariaRegionId            = ALNO.NotariaRegionId
                                 AND ALNA.NotariaDistritoId          = ALNO.NotariaDistritoId
                                 AND ALNA.NotariaId                  = ALNO.NotariaId
                                 AND ALS.CveFteMT                    = ALNO.CveFteMT
                                 AND ALS.NotariaPaisId               = ALNO.NotariaPaisId
                                 AND ALS.NotariaEntidadFederativaId  = ALNO.NotariaEntidadFederativaId
                                 AND ALS.NotariaId                   = ALNO.NotariaId
                                 AND ALS.NotarioId                   = ALNO.NotarioId
                                 AND ALS.NotariaRegionId             = ALNO.NotariaRegionId
                                 AND ALS.NotariaMunicipioId          = ALNO.NotariaMunicipioId
                                 AND ALS.NotariaDistritoId           = ALNO.NotariaDistritoId 
WHERE ALS.CveFteMT                 = 'MREYNOSA'
AND   ALS.STrasladoDominioEstado   = 'P'
AND   MONTH(STrasladoDominioFecha) = 3
AND   YEAR(STrasladoDominioFecha)  = 2023;
```

Comment: o sea que no estan filtrando datos? pero si vendrían los datos por MREYNOSA, 'P' y por su rango de fechas no?